# How to only allow server-side submissions only once a day

Tags: server-side

I've created a simple online form which when submitted will send data to my server.

The thing is that I only want the person using the form to only be able to use the form only "ONCE A DAY", how do I accomplish this?

Below is the Input Form and the Action Page....

============================

## ONLINE FORM

```
<table  border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" height="90%">
<tr>
<td style="align: center;">
<br>
<div style="font-family: Eurostile, Impact; font-size:18px; color: #9f9f9f; align: center;">before you</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">


<form name="RedpointsForm" action="http://blainevk.isexypartynetwork.net/redpoints/test-promo-upload.php" method="post" />
<input type="hidden" name="points" id="points" value="23">
<input type="hidden" name="useridV" id="useridV" value="56">

<input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="V">
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo strtotime("now"); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="notes" id="notes" value="iSexy Contest / Burkhart's Pub, 1233 Piedmont Ave. Atlanta, GA 30324">


<div style="font-family: Eurostile, Impact; font-size:18px; color: #9f9f9f; line-height:120%">User ID: <input type="input" name="userid" id="userid"></div><br>

<input type="image" src="rainbow.gif" name="image" width="60" height="60">
</form>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

============================

## ACTION PAGE

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'XXXXXXXXX');
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXXXXXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXXX');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['userid'];
$value2 = $_POST['useridV'];
$value3 = $_POST['type'];
$value4= $_POST['points'];
$value5= $_POST['notes'];
$value6= $_POST['date'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO bcse_points (userid, useridV, type, points, notes, date) VALUES ('$value','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

=====================

Thanks in advance.

Looking forward to a response,
Blaine.

Comment: You haven't posted any code to indicate how you plan to prevent more than one submission per day--since this is the problem you want to solve, it would be more appropriate to post this code than the submission form. Please see the StackOverflow guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

if your users has to login before filling any forms you can simply connect each submited form to  the specific user by foreign key and tho you will know which forms has been submited by each user.

The second idea is to create a data table in your database  and store IP adress of devices from which the form has been filled. After every single submition you will have to set a timer to 24h, when it reaches the end IP will be removed from db.